# Rendering variable to ejs template?

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt, ejs

My ejs side (webpage) is updating the wrong variables every time I refresh the page,but each variable has a different name. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

My index.js is receiving messages from an esp8266 using MQTT, and then I render that to the ejs.

**index.js**

```
var topicTemp = "FromESPtoWeb/temp";
var topicMessagemoisture = "FromESPtoWeb/moisture";

var content = { doorMsg: "Door Closed" ,
                windowMsg: "Window Closed",
                tempMsg : "",
                moistureMsg : "" ,
                motionMsg: "Motion" };

 client.on('connect', function () {

    //Subscribe to topic "FromESPtoWeb/temp"
    client.subscribe(topicTemp, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }

        client.on('message', function (topicTemp, temp) {
            console.log(temp.toString());
            content.tempMsg = temp.toString();
        });

    }) 
  //Subscribe to topic "FromESPtoWeb/moisture"   
   client.subscribe(topicMessagemoisture, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }

        client.on('message', function (topicMoisture, moisture) {
            console.log("new message on " + topicMoisture + " - " + 
            moisture.toString());
            content.moistureMsg = moisture.toString();
        });
    })

})

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {  content : content } );
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<h4> <%= content.moistureMsg %> </h4>
<h4> <%= content.motionMsg %> </h4>
<h4> <%= content.windowMsg %> </h4>
<h4> <%= content.doorMsg %> </h4>
```

**content.moistureMsg** sometimes showing what is suppose to be to **content.windowMsg** , or **content.doorMsg** is showing the value that is suppose to be to **content.motionMsg**. A complete mess...

Comment: You've not shown how the variables are updated, so we have no chance of working out what's going on.

Comment: Try `console.log(content)` before the render call

Comment: @hardillb I added the part it was missing, I didn't want to put the whole thing not to be confusing, but you are right, without that, it will be hard to understand what I need.

Comment: @jro it is printing { doorMsg: 'Door Closed',
  windowMsg: 'Window Closed',
  tempMsg: '  6.09',
  moistureMsg: '  6.09',
  motionMsg: 'Motion' }
. tempMsg:  and moistureMsg:  are printing the same value (6.09). Which doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: If you have an solution add it as an answer, not as an edit to the question. That way you can mark it as accepted so others can find it easier. Also do not edit the title to include `[solved]`, that is what an accepted answer is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the request object!.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('index', { content : req.content } ); 
});
```

Comment: Why? The `content` variable is not part of the request object

Answer (score 0):

**My understanding was very wrong about client.on and subscribe. I rebuilt the whole code, and now it is working.**

```
var topicTemp = "FromESPtoWeb/temp";
var topicDoor = "FromESPtoWeb/door";
var topicWindow = "FromESPtoWeb/window";
var topicMoisture = "FromESPtoWeb/moisture";
var topicMotion = "FromESPtoWeb/motion";

var content = { doorMsg: "Door Closed" , windowMsg: "Window Closed", tempMsg:"", moistureMsg:"", motionMsg: ""};



client.on('connect', function () {

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        if(topic === topicTemp) {
            temp(message);
        }
        if(topic === topicDoor) {
            door(message);
        }
        if(topic === topicWindow) {
            window(message);
        }
        if(topic === topicMoisture) {
            moisture(message);
        }
        if(topic === topicMotion) {
            motion(message);
        }

    });

    client.subscribe(topicTemp, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }
    });
    client.subscribe(topicDoor, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }
    });
    client.subscribe(topicWindow, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }
    });
    client.subscribe(topicMoisture, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }
    });
    client.subscribe(topicMotion, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("something went wrong on subscribe to message");
        }
    });


});

var temp = (message) => {
    console.log(message.toString());
    content.tempMsg = message.toString();
}
var door = (message) => {
    if (message == "Door Open") {
        console.log("Door open");
        content.doorMsg = message;
    }else if (message == "Door Closed") {
        console.log("Door closed");
        content.doorMsg = message;
    }
}
var window = (message) => {
    if (message == "Window Open") {
        console.log("window open");
        content.windowMsg = message;
    }else if (message == "Window Closed") {
        console.log("window closed");
        content.windowMsg = message;
    }
}
var moisture = (message) => {
    console.log(message.toString());
    content.moistureMsg = message.toString();
}
var motion = (message) => {
    console.log(message.toString());
    content.motionMsg = message.toString();
}
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {  content : content } );
});
```